# How to achieve forward declaration of class template

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, forward-declaration

I am trying to create a `Graph` class by using Nested Classes `Vertex` and `Edge`. I want to make my `Vertex` class to accept generic parameters. I have forward declared my `Vertex` class so that I can use it in my `Edge` Class.

When I use templates, I get few errors that I am not sure how to resolve.

Here is what I tried. The errors are commented out next to each line.

```
class Graph
{
    private:
        template <class T>
        class Vertex; // Forward Declaration

        template <class T>
        vector<Vertex<T> > vertices; // Err: member 'vertices' declared as a template

        class Edge
        {
            public:
                template <class T>
                Vertex<T>& _orig; // Err: member '_orig' declared as a template

                template <class T>
                Vertex<T>& _dest; // Err: member '_dest' declared as a template

                template <class T>
                Edge(Vertex<T>& orig, Vertex<T>& dest) : _orig(orig), // Err: member initializer '_orig' does not name a non-static data member or base class
                                                         _dest(dest) { }

                template <class T>
                Vertex<T>& getOrig() { return _orig; } // Err: use of undeclared identifier '_orig'

                template <class T>
                Vertex<T>& getDest() { return _dest; } // Err: use of undeclared identifier '_dest'
        };

        template <typename T>
        class Vertex
        {
            public:
                T _data;
                vector<Edge> _edges;

                Vertex(T data) : _data(data) { }

                void addEdgeToVertex(Edge& edge)
                {
                    _edges.push_back(edge);
                }
        };

    public:
        template <typename T>
        void addEdge(Vertex<T>& orig, Vertex<T>& dest)
        {
            Edge edge(orig, dest);
            orig.addEdgeToVertex(edge);
            dest.addEdgeToVertex(edge);
        }
};
```

Can you please help me in pointing out what I am doing wrong? How can I fix this code?

Comment: Simplify the problem: see how to declare a template data member that doesn't require a forward declaration.

Comment: you cannot have template variables that isn't static...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The forward declaration looks fine. The problem is that you can't declare "template member variable", how could you specify the template argument for them?

You should make class template instead.

```
template <class E>
class Graph
{
    private:
        template <class T>
        class Vertex; // Forward Declaration

        vector<Vertex<E> > vertices;
    ...
};
```

It's same for class `Edge` too.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/MAIV23385)

Comment: Thanks. I got the solution. But I don't quite understand it. Can you please explain what does template <class E> Graph mean? 
i.e.   template <class T>
        class Vertex; 
        vector<Vertex<E> > vertices; 
in layman's term. Sorry this is really confusing to me.

Comment: i.e. If my data is of type string, then both 'E' and 'T' will be string right ?

Comment: @SyncMaster If you use `Graph` like `Graph<std::string> g;`, then the template parameter `E` will be `std::string`, the member `vertices` will be `vector<Vertex<std::string>>`. Then in `Vertex`, `_data` will be `std::string`, `_edges` will be `vector<Edge<std::string>>`.